# cursorMark is stateless and how it solves deep paging

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solr4

as specified [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) cursormark is stateless but I don't get how it it is solving deep paging issue if its stateless. Does solr stores the indexed data in sort by unique key field if so then it will clarify my confusion.

if I am wrong please explain how the cursormark solves deep paging. Because as cursormark is stateless it also need to sort and claculate cursormark every time request a query and this is similar to start=#start-position.

Comment: You have the documentation to explain the usage. If you want to understand the implementation, the source is always available. The depth of your question is best answered by consulting that directly.

Comment: Hi alex,
I post this question because I don't get / understand  the documentation.

Anyway thanks I should really study the doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link you referenced...

> Cursors in Solr are a logical concept, that doesn't involve caching any state information on the server.  ***Instead the sort values of the last document returned to the client are used to compute a "mark" representing a logical point in the ordered space of sort values.*** That "mark" can be specified in the parameters of subsequent requests to tell Solr where to continue.

This is elaborated further in an explanation of the constraints on using cursorMark...

> ***Cursor mark values are computed based on the sort values of each document in the result***, which means multiple documents with identical sort values will produce identical Cursor mark values if one of them is the last document on a page of results.  In that situation, the subsequent request using that cursorMark would not know which of the documents with the identical mark values should be skipped. ***Requiring that the uniqueKey field be used as a clause in the sort criteria guarantees that a deterministic ordering will be returned, and that every cursorMark value will identify a unique point in the sequence of documents.***

If this doesn't help clarify things for you, the next best explanation i can offer is to think of the cursorMark as an encoded *filter* telling Solr to skip all documents with values in the sort field(s) that come "before" (based on the asc/desc sort order) some specific values.

Comment: in your last paragraph, you're telling about an encoded filter that tells which documents to skip. So does that mean Solr searches again on every new page and then it simply skips rows that come "before"? It's either it remembers the results or it searches again to get the next page. I still don't understand how it solves it efficiently.

Comment: You also mentioned "cursorMark value will identify a unique point in the sequence of documents". How does it know, on every page requests, what the sequence of documents is without remembering it from the previous request? How would it compute the next cursorMark if it doesn't remember anything or it doesn't perform another search?

Comment: The cursorMark is just an encoding of the unique sort column's values. So if you're sorting by date and id, then it's just the date & ID values of the next document. Even if the next document is deleted, these values point to where it 'would' be so can be used to begin the next search.